# How do I collapse a CSS grid row when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

When the checkbox is checked the nav panel should appear, and unchecked, it should be hidden. The problem is that I setup my titlebars with CSS Grid layout, so I don't know how to make the bottom row disappear.

The only thing I know is that there is a `:checked` pseudo selector for checkboxes and radio buttons, etc.. I just need to make the second row disappear when that checkbox is checked.

```css
     @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:900|Rajdhani|Quicksand');
    
    /* Global */
    
    html > * {
     font-family: Quicksand;
    }
    
    body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
    
    header {
     background: #414a4c;
    }
    
    /* ID's */
    #navbar {
     list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    #navbar li {
     display: inline;
     padding-left: 35px;
    }
    
    #navbar a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: white;
    
    }
    
    #navbar-toggle:checked {
    
    }
    
    /* Classes */
    
    .title-grid {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
     grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
     grid-template-areas: 
      "text . . clock"
      "nav nav . .";
     width: 100%;
     grid-row-gap: 5vh;
    }
    
    .title-grid #navbar-toggle,
    .title-grid label {
     grid-area: text;
     left: 0;
     margin-left: 25px;
     
    }
    
    .title-grid #titletext {
     grid-area: text;
     position: absolute;
     left: 150px;
    }
    
    .title-grid nav {
     grid-area: nav;
    }
    
    .title-grid #clock {
     grid-area: clock;
     font-family: Rajdhani, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size: 30px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    /* Keyframes */
```

```html
        <header>
    
            <div class="title-grid">
                <span id="clock"></span>
                <input type="checkbox" name="navbar-toggle" id="navbar-toggle">
                <label for="navbar-toggle">
                    <i>
                        <img src="resources/img/menu-toggle.svg" height="35px" width="35px" alt="Menu Toggle">
                    </i>
                </label>
                <div id="titletext">
                    <h1>
                        50-0 Protocol &copy;
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="navbar">
                        <li><a href="Index.html" class="active">Students</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Teachers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: Your code (it should be [mcve]) has an error reported due to the non-existent `mainClock()` function call. Now, do we *need* any of the HTML other than the `<header>` element (and its children)? If not, please remove it. Do we need all the CSS? If not, please remove it. It's easier for us to help if we don't have to winnow out the unnecessary code ourselves.

Comment: all the css is relevant but the html i can see wym sorry and the clock function is javascript and literally creates a live clock so isnt necessary but there ya go

Answer (score 2):

Add these styles

```
#navbar-toggle~nav {
  display: none;
}

#navbar-toggle:checked~nav {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:900|Rajdhani|Quicksand');

/* Global */

html>* {
  font-family: Quicksand;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background: #414a4c;
}


/* ID's */

#navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

#navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#navbar-toggle~nav {
  display: none;
}

#navbar-toggle:checked~nav {
  display: block;
}


/* Classes */

.title-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "text . . clock" "nav nav . .";
  width: 100%;
  grid-row-gap: 5vh;
}

.title-grid #navbar-toggle,
.title-grid label {
  grid-area: text;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.title-grid #titletext {
  grid-area: text;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
}

.title-grid nav {
  grid-area: nav;
}

.title-grid #clock {
  grid-area: clock;
  font-family: Rajdhani, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* Keyframes */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/main.css">
<script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>50-0 Protocol </title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <div class="title-grid">
      <span id="clock"></span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="navbar-toggle" id="navbar-toggle">
      <label for="navbar-toggle">
                <i>
                    <img src="resources/img/menu-toggle.svg" height="35px" width="35px" alt="Menu Toggle">
                </i>
            </label>
      <div id="titletext">
        <h1>
          50-0 Protocol &copy;
        </h1>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul id="navbar">
          <li><a href="Index.html" class="active">Students</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Teachers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you explain what the ~ does so i can apply this in future projects if required?

Comment: Also i dont want to just hide the text i want to collapse the grid row

Comment: ~ is a sibling selector . It selects a sibling element  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Comment: What do you mean by collapse the grid row?

Comment: so when the box isnt checked rearrange the grid so only the top row is visible because if you just hide the text the bg color of the second row will still appear i want to gety rid of that completely so i can animate it with a transition

Comment: Sorry no idea about grids :(

Comment: @JFWebDesign What nandita has answered with is the basic method you would need to use to accomplish this with CSS. It sounds like you have some more details/information on what conditions you have that should be added to your question so that others can provide more complete answers. This could also be done with JavaScript. If you are open to JavaScript solutions, you should add the JavaScript tag to the question.

Comment: The tricky thing with the `~` selector is it can't go back up a level. If you want broader control over the entire nav place your checkbox outside of it and position it absolutely. This will let you use `~` on the siblings and a sibling's children.